# Python не хочет принимать словарь в функцию

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот мой код -

```
stats = {
        "PLm" : PLm,
         }
def MTGWU(**stats):
    time.sleep(0.4)
    while True:
        print(stats)
        PLm = stats["PLm"]
```

Ошибка которую выдаёт:

```
TypeError: MTGWU() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: покажите как вы его вызываете

Comment: x = threading.Thread(target=MTGWU, args=(**stats))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо писать так:

```
def MTGWU(**stats):
...
MTGWU(**stats)
```

либо так:

```
def MTGWU(stats):
...
MTGWU(stats)
```

В вашем случае лучше использовать второй вариант и вызывать функцию так:

```
threading.Thread(target=MTGWU, args=(stats, ))
```

Comment: забыл уточнить,это фкнкция для отдельного потока,поэтому когда я делаю

x = threading.Thread(target=MTGWU, args=(**stats))

мне говорят

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @lo1chik тогда используйте второй вариант

Comment: TypeError: MTGWU() takes 1 positional argument but 14 were given